# Moving from XIB (aka NIB) file to Main.storyboard and the init method is not called

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, xib, nib, xcode-storyboard

I've always wanted to launch a word game, so 2 weeks ago I have purchased an app template.

Unfortunately, the purchased source code uses XIB files (and does not use ARC) - and I would like to change that.

So I have added a Main.storyboard file and have copied the contents of the first XIB file into it. I have ctrl-dragged the properties, set the "Is Initial View Controller" checkbox and specified "Main" as "Main storyboard file base name" (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGtI2.png)):

[image: Xcode]

Unfortunately, I see in debugger, that the code which was located in the `init` method of the HomeViewController.m is not run (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCIbl.png)):

[image: Xcode]

So my question is: how to rename the `init` method, so that it is run again - when using storyboard instead of NIB files?

I guess my question is very simple for seasoned iOS programmers, but I couldn't find the answer myself (for example in the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) by Apple).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution for moving from XIB to storyboard:

- Move the code from `init` to `initWithCoder:`
- And adapt the Core Data code, because `initWithCoder:` is being called after the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (while the `init` was called before)